# Privacy-focused remote desktop tool/service

Tags: open-source, remote-access, privacy, remote-desktop

Could somebody advise any safe remote desktop service?
By privacy-oriented, I mean:

1. Open source
2. Encrypted
3. Sends to third-party servers only the minimum amount of information required to establish a connection

Why not just SSH etc:

1. PC may be behind NAT
2. Requires pre-installation to the target PC or moderately skillfull user to install and set it up

Ideally, something like teamviewer, but satisfying the first 3 items. OS: Windows and/or Linux

Comment: Did you ever find any solution for this matter?

Comment: No. That is why I ask the question )

Comment: I considered such solutions like TigerVNC (and other *VNCs), Chrome Remote Desktop etc. But they are either not open source, or require server with globally routable IP, or/and are not maintained for a long time.